# Monitoring Java standalone application with ping url

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a monitoring tool which accepts url (http) address to be configured and it will give the memory usage and all those stuffs whether it is alive or not. I need to monitor a standalone java application to be monitored using that tool. Most obvious answer was deploying that application in a server and use that url. But my requirements is not to use servlet container at all.

Please suggest any option so that we can have ping url type on top of a standlone application so that i can feed it to the monitoring tool.

Comment: Basic `ServerSocket` that respond in plain html ?

Comment: I have a similar scenario and would like to know, what is the tool that you were using to monitor? appreciate your help.